# Rails TypeError when passing a object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, typeerror, symbols

I was creating a tableless model in Rails 4 for supporting sending emails easily.

So i have the following model:

```
class Message
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :subject, :content, :email
end
```

The following controller:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end

 def create
   message = Message.new(params[:message])
   if message.valid?
     UserMailer.send(message)
     redirect_to :back, :notice => "Email was successfully sent."
   else
     flash[:alert] = "You must fill all fields."
     render 'new'
   end
 end
end
```

The form:

```
<%= form_for @message do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>

  <%= f.label :subject %>
  <%= f.text_field :subject %>

  <%= f.label :content %>
  <%= f.text_area :content, rows: 5, class: 'span7' %>
  <%= f.submit "Send Email", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>

<% end %>
```

But when i try to send an email here i what i got:

```
#<Message:0x007fcc98e8c760 @errors=#    <ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fcc98e96788 @base=#<Message:0x007fcc98e8c760 ...>, @messages={}>,     @email="sdsadas@adasdas.com", @subject="adasdas", @content="asdsad", @validation_context=nil> is not a symbol
```

The error says its in here UserMailer.send(message)

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Kernel.send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-send) method that you're calling on `UserMailer` only accepts a symbol or a string, whereas you're attempting to pass it an instance of `Message`. You're probably looking for some other method of `UserMailer`. Generally you'll be defining and calling your own method on an `ActionMailer::Base` subclass. See [the guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) for details.

Comment: thanks i figured it out, yes it was because i named the method send, i changed the name and it was good =)